# manually applying a colormap loses the set_bad property

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, colormap

I want to save on disk a colormapped image (that is, a grayscale image with a colormap applied to it). Most of its values are `np.nan`s, which I would like to keep with a special colour (e.g. red). 
It works if I plot the image with `plt.imshow`, but not if I apply the colormap separately.

This is an example code that shows the behaviour:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import PIL.Image as Image

a = np.zeros((20, 20))
a[10, 10] = 10
a[a == 0] = np.nan

current_cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('viridis')
current_cmap.set_bad(color='red')
plt.imshow(a, vmin=0, vmax=20)
```

[image]

That's what I would like to save on disk (as a png, not as a matplotlib figure). I would normally use PIL for saving arrays.

```
norm = plt.Normalize(0, 20)
b = current_cmap(norm(a))
Image.fromarray(np.uint8(b * 255)).show()
```

[image]

(Shown with my OS image viewer which applies some interpolation when zooming). I can see the center is colormapped just fine, but I lose the red colours for the nans.

Overall, I am doing this because I want to save the the output of imshow to disk with the right colormap and the right nan's colours, so any solution to this problem would work for me.

Answer (score 0):

As documented here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9892 
the solution is

```
norm = plt.Normalize(0, 20)
b = current_cmap(np.ma.masked_invalid(norm(a)))
Image.fromarray(np.uint8(b * 255)).show()
```